# what's an easy way to cast one object to another (same props)

Tags: c#, .net

What's an easy way to cast one object to another when they have the same properties?  For example:

```
public class Test1
{
   public string FirstName{ get; set; }
   public string LastName{ get; set; }
}

public class Test2
{
   public string FirstName{ get; set; }
   public string LastName{ get; set; }
}
```

So if I have a populated Test1 object and I want all of its values to be populated into Test2, then what's the easiest way to do that?  I know I can set values 1-by-1 from Test1 to Test2 but I was wondering if you could recommend a quicker, easier way?  Like test1.Map(test2) or something like that?

Comment: You want to have Automapper

Comment: You can use inheritance.

Comment: You use the word "cast", but you don't appear to actually be talking about casting. See marked duplicate for the answer to what you _do_ seem to be talking about.

Answer (score 0):

If one can be inherited from the other:

```
public class Test1 {
   public string FirstName{ get; set; }
   public string LastName { get; set; }
}

public class Test2 : Test1 { }
```

then simple cast :

```
Test2 test2 = new Test2 { FirstName = "A", LastName = "B" };
Test1 test1 = test2;                                         // or var test1 = (Test1)test2;
```